# sfcgal ST_Volume Issue

Tags: postgis, volume, sfcgal, st

ST_Volume works with shape data pasted into the query in this form:

```
SELECT (abs(ST_Volume(design)) -     
        abs(ST_Volume(ST_3DIntersection(design,scan))))

FROM   (SELECT (ST_MakeSolid('POLYHEDRALSURFACEZ( ...definition goes here...) ')) AS design,

(ST_MakeSolid('POLYHEDRALSURFACEZ(...definition goes here...)'))  AS scan )

AS t;
```

But if I enter the data into a table and try to read it into the query, in this way, ST_Volume outputs 0:

```
WITH sd AS (SELECT data_value AS design 
        FROM data
        WHERE data_label = '3D Design TINZ'),
     ss AS      (SELECT data_value AS scan  
        FROM data
        WHERE data_label = '3D Scan TINZ')

SELECT 
sd.design,
ST_IsSolid(sd.design) ,
ST_IsSolid(ST_MakeSolid(sd.design)) ,
ST_Volume(ST_MakeSolid(sd.design)),
ST_Volume(ST_MakeSolid(ST_GeomFromText(sd.design))),
ST_3DArea(sd.design),
ST_3DIntersection(sd.design,ss.scan)
FROM sd,ss;
```

Output is:

[image]

So the ST_MakeSolid toggles ST_IsSolid from false to true, but the ST_Volume function returns 0, meaning that it does not recognise the input as a solid, or ...?

But the ST_3DArea and ST_3DIntersections functions appear to work fine.

Comment: It is impossible to tell without seeing the input geometries. I can only guess that if ST_Volume returns 0, but there are otherwise no errors, then your solid is not, in fact, closed and therefore has no volume.. It is quite easy to construct an object that return true to ST_IsSolid, a value for ST_3dArea, and 0 for ST_Volumne. For example, `SELECT ST_IsSolid(ST_Makesolid(ST_Force3d(ST_Buffer(ST_Makepoint(0,0), 2))));` which returns, true, 12.4857806090322, and 0 for those 3 functions.

Comment: The test shapes have 47 and 959 vertices, respectively, so it's not trivial to manually check closure or legality. Volume execution time for these shapes is 4 minutes. Actual data has 2807 and 72587 vertices, respectively. This has never completed.

Comment: Yeah, sure, this stuff is very non-trivial on lots of levels. I have generally found polyhedral surfaces behave better than TINs and, also, for larger data sets the runtimes are slow. There needs to be some kind of make valid function for 3d, says the non-C programmer.

Comment: what's the above output if you pass in *geometry* types rather than the WKT as *text*? most of those functions don't validate their input, and AFAIK `ST_MakeSolid` pretty much simply sets anything to *solid*? are you sure it worked as expected in your first example?

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer but a workaround:

Changing the TINZ prefix in the input data file to POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z
then works with:

```
ST_Volume(ST_MakeSolid(sd.design))
```

Maybe there are some polygons within the data files that are not actually triangles, making the TINZ definition invalid.